# Parsing string 0x11 as integer exception

Tags: java, exception, int

I'm trying to parse the string "0x11" as an int but when i do, java thow a NumberFormatException..

I already tried the following:

```
Integer.parseInt("0x11", 16));
```

Thanks to help me because i'm clueless right now :)

Comment: This line of code does not throw an exception. Are you **sure** that's the source of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `0x` part. Remove it and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to drop the "0x" notation to use this method.

Also you have an extra ) in there.

See the way formatting works on the javadocs:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove 0x from your string. You've already specified your radix with 16.

```
Integer.parseInt("11", 16);
```